# Who remembers how they found Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, fun

Who remembers how they found Stack Overflow?

Because for the life of me I can't and it's really bugging me.

Maybe one of you found it the same way I did and can remind me...

Comment: Sorry. Sorry to you Specer as well. Can anybody undo his CW?

Comment: Bah. Now I can't turn it off... oh well. No one was upvoting it anyway.

Comment: fun?  I hate fun!

Comment: I don't see how this is closed while [other](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159186/are-there-any-secret-hats) [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52958/anyone-interested-in-learning-more-about-stack-overflow) [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) aren't...

Comment: @ColeJohnson the `Many Memes of Meta` is actually a valuable resource as there are a lot of inside jokes that are easier to point to that question for answers than explaining over and over again.  But I won't argue on the others as they don't have the same value.

Comment: You mean how i met SO ? Sure, when my code failed and i could not figure out why - public static void mian(Strings[]arg){System.out.println("Goodbye cruel world");}

Answer (score 34):

I was an avid reader of [Jeff's Atwood blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/). He first started talking about it, and the rest was history.

(I actually found Jeff Atwood's blog through [StumbleUpon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StumbleUpon).)

Comment: Who the hell is Jeff?

Comment: ... and why do we keep talking about him?

Comment: Same here, but I thought Jeff's blog was a joke site at first because of its confusing title (as much in vein as in TheDailyWTF). This was wa-a-a-ay back…

Answer (score 25):

[Joel Spolsky's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) [blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html).

Comment: Same here. Found out about it when Joel kicked off the podcast.

Answer (score 18):

I believe it was [GirlDeveloper's blog](http://girldeveloper.com/intar-social-commentary/stackoverflow-the-answer-to-quot-site-expertsexchange-quot/) (aka [Sara Chipps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4140/sara-chipps)) that first put me onto it, although I didn't join until it came out of private beta. Thanks to that blog post I'd *heard* of it, and [Douglas Leeder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3978/douglas-leeder) (a close friend) probably mentioned it too.

I started writing a [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/09/28/new-addiction-stack-overflow.aspx) about the possibility of getting addicted to SO on the evening of the day I joined (September 26th 2008) although the actual post didn't go out until the Sunday evening.

Comment: I've run across her blog in the past... though I can't remember if it was before or after I got here.

Comment: I first saw her blog because it mentioned C# in Depth (on my birthday, in fact).

Comment: "I'll readily admit that the reputation side of things appeals to my ego." haha nice. Hows that ego feeling? ;)

Comment: @Jon Skeet and that's when you left microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp

Comment: @Sasha: Very soon after, yes. For a while I tried to do both, but I don't have the time and I was forever wishing I had WMD when writing newsgroup posts. I do miss detailed discussions though...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why downvote? I'd say envious people... ;)

Answer (score 11):

I believe I found it by searching a question on Google. A Stack Overflow question was the first result. I pretty much just joined to get rid of that annoying "First time here? Check out the FAQ" thing that kept popping up. I never believed I would get more than 100 rep, let alone 7,000.

Comment: Same here. I notices I keep finding SO on google. At first I thought it was a blog, but it didn't seem quite right (something like "this Stack Overflow guy is good"). When I read the FAQ I imminently wanted to join - it just seemed awesome.

Answer (score 7):

I think Stack Overflow gradually entered my consciousness. It would come up fairly often when googling programming questions, and I think one day, it just sort of hit me that there was something special about Stack Overflow.

It was probably the aesthetics I noticed first--the site has a really clean, inviting look, and code blocks are formatted just how you'd like them to be. So, I bookmarked it and started going there first when I needed help. Soon after that, I started to notice the reputation score and badges. I had seen reputation ratings on other sites, but it seemed to stand out more on Stack Overflow. I could see the power of it. It's like a competition to see who can be the most cooperative. It was then that I joined.

Answer (score 4):

Rich B made me.  Seriously.

Comment: @TheTXI: That sound you just heard was the sonic boom Jeff made as he rushed to remove your mod powers.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* it was through some arbitrary blog post saying "Stack Overflow out of private beta" or something along those lines.  I had never heard of it before, so I decided to check it out.  It did not disappoint.

Answer (score 2):

Haackoverflow from [PDC](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC21/).

Comment: Ditto, except I saw it on Phil's blog: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/07/haackoverflow-vs-stackoverflow.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I follow both Jeff and Joel on their blogs, so I started listening to the podcast from episode 1.

Answer (score 2):

I saw it first on [Jon Skeet's blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Stack+Overflow/default.aspx). At the time, like Jon Skeet, I was a [Usenet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) frequenter, and I remember thinking two things:

- Pah! Yet another web site; can't beat good ol' [NNTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_News_Transfer_Protocol)
- But if Jon Skeet is busy there... ;-p

I didn't join for another week or so, when I finally decided to give it a whirl. I was hopelessly hooked soon after.

I kept trying to convince myself that Jon Skeet's lead was just that fortnight's headstart... but that excuse simply isn't cutting it any more ;-p

Answer (score 2):

I googled some Java question or another and a Stack Overflow post was the most useful result. That single experience wasn't enough to hook me, but the top Google result for the very next question I had was also a Stack Overflow post. So I took a closer look, signed up, and started answering questions...

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember the exact timeline, but [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) mentioned it either on Hanselminutes or in his blog. This would have been approximately when Preview 5 was out, and I had just started an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) project so was mainly interested from that perspective. ("Hey, here's a really cool site that is built in ASP.NET MVC!")

Answer (score 2):

I saw it mentioned on [comp.lang.c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comp.*_hierarchy#Partial_list_of_comp..2A_groups) where someone linked to an answer on Stack Overflow to ask if it was 'best practice'.

I'm pretty sure it was someone getting help working through the [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) exercises, if memory serves. My first thought was:

> The good folks at Experts-Exchange are
>   just going to ***love*** this!

Naturally, I realized that participating in Stack Overflow was the best way to exact revenge for every time I hit a pay wall in search of a good answer.

There weren't many people answering questions on Linux / [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) / Linux-kernel, and not nearly as many people answering in the [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) tag, so I found my home there and have been there ever since :)

Answer (score 1):

[Jon Galloway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5/jon-galloway) asked me to see if I could create mischief (nicely, reporting how) after some beta testers had already been naughty hackers.

Answer (score 1):

I first heard mention of Stack Overflow on [one of Doug's blog posts](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/01/07/binning-data-in-matlab/) at [The MathWorks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathWorks).

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember, I joined a while ago. I can remember being a big fan of it almost right away though. The clear interface, and the quality and speed of the answers impressed me! When you're used to asking on a forum and then coming back a day later to someone who has a equal misunderstanding of the issue then Stack Overflow was light years ahead.

My first question was *[Getting the ID of an embedded ASP Object using JavaScript and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272007/getting-id-of-embedded-asp-object-using-javascript-and-jquery)*.

Look at the quality of the answers.

Comment: Yeah. I was a big contributor on Experts-Exchange and I definitely felt this was much better right away. EEs interface feels so cluttered.

Comment: @Spencer <aol>Me too</aol>  Even if EE's T-shirts are free.  8-)

Comment: They're so uncomfortable though! The big ass prints should be on the back. I have 5 and I never wear any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to find [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/), at about the same time that [Jeff Atwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) and [Joel Spolsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) started talking about Stack Overflow. I honestly don't remember how I found out about Coding Horror.

Comment: It had to have been around mid April 2008, because I remember hearing the first podcast. I also think that the post about the podcast was the first entry I read on Coding Horror. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001101.html

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I've been here for 6 months already!? Well, according to my account, Jan. 13 was the day of [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440017/net-options-stream-video-files-as-webcam-image). Correlating that to my [Google History](http://www.google.com/history/), on Jan 13 I was looking up a friend by his screenname. It rendered a stackoverflow account - I viewed it, and two other search results. Signed up thereafter.

How's that for MacGyver?

Answer (score 0):

A link to [Joel Spolsky's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) [blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) from [use.perl.org](http://use.perl.org/). It was kind of like "Get over there before and support Perl!" So here I am. The Perl expert category wasn't quite as glutted as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

In the Programming Symposium subforum on [Ars Technica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Technica).

Answer (score 0):

I think I first saw it in the [Google Tech Talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AtGoogleTalks#List_of_speakers.2C_by_category_and_date) *[Learning from StackOverflow.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ)* by Joel Spolsky (2009-04-24).

Answer (score 0):

Someone linked to the programmer joke 'question' that was closed/deleted some time ago on a gaming forum. For a while, I had thought of SO as a sort of joke forum for programmers. Having  forgot the name of the site but distinctively remembering the design of the site, I managed to find it again several months later when I signed up as I was getting into web design.

Since then, I discovered the SE network and have participated in many sites (with varying degrees of activity).

Answer (score 0):

I saw it mentioned on http://reddit.com/r/programming several times while it was being developed. When [Stack Overflow Private Beta Begins](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/) was finally announced, I didn't immediately join because Jeff Atwood made me feel "*eww... Microsoft*".

However, my repeated feelings of "*eww... [Experts-Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange)*" were much stronger, and I quickly conceded since that this was likely to become the primary programming resource, I wouldn't be avoiding it forever and may as well get on board as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I needed help with my [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) project. That's when I searched and found this site :)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for answers to simple programming questions, and 9 times out of 10, the first link (and most helpful) was to Stack Overflow. I used these for a while, and then I had a few questions that I wanted to ask, so I made an account.

Answer (score -2):

I was introduced to Stack Overflow by a colleague. (Who is also the chief architect in our R&D team, and my direct superior.)