# Are there any secret hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012, secret-hats

Wondering if anyone has unlocked any secret hats. A beret perhaps.

Comment: They wouldn't exactly be secret if you got answered, would they?

Comment: Someone was going to ask sooner or later, no list needed, just curious :D

Comment: I know the thoughts of your mind---you just wanted to get yourself a *hat*!

Comment: I am shocked, _shocked_ that you would think that! \*lovingly strokes my fez\*

Comment: Voted NC since the accepted answer is literally a bunch of blank lines

Comment: Voted to reopen to see if it gives a secret hat!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks to vote to reopen :) I gave a new secret hat :)

Comment: @hims056 you mean the cupcake?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd NO. I mean [Gotta Catch 'Em All!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159521/187824) :)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Yes, and here's a list of them:

> 

Collect them all!

Comment: Oh, I love the third one!

Comment: You're just trying to get more hats, aren't you?

Comment: You got one of them wrong.

Comment: They're written in such invisible ink that they even appear in the same colour as the background when viewing the source.

Comment: Their names are all made up of non-printable characters. (As distinct from non-printable *words*.)

Comment: @Anna Lear: Which one?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn it'd be too easy if I told you, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AnnaLear There is nothing wrong with easy.

Comment: Confirming I just received "The Emperors New Hat".

Comment: What's this hunter2 hat?

Comment: -1. You are missing <li>s in your list.

Comment: How many of you highlighted the answer on the off chance that there was white-colored text in there?

Comment: You're not using the spoiler tag.

Comment: @chirale: Fixed.

Comment: I have one on SO, I want to know so badly what I got it for

Comment: That is some chilly spoilers above.  Brrrr.

Comment: you gave me a heart attack because I thought there was a css bug with the spoiler block. have a upvote anyways.

Answer (score 39):

It looks like there are 3 secret hats. I found the following in the [sprite image](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/sprite-128.png) used to display the hats that are not described on the [winterbash site](http://winterba.sh/):

[image: easter egg hats in sprite]

[image: full sprite]

Also, these three hats aren't in the sprite at all:

[image: nonspritehat] [image: pirate] [image: red beard]

Comment: nice approach to find them :)

Comment: How to find such sprite image?

Comment: @hims056 you can see by firebug

Comment: Not all of them are here - could there be others? Or is this sprite meant to fool us all?

Comment: @irrelephant you can see this in stack overflow not in meta ... check edited answer ]

Comment: Yes, but for example the "n00b Hat" in Yannis' answer is not on this sprite.

Comment: @irrelephant than it might possible they have either modified or have other image

Comment: If they knew that we would look in the sprite image (we're programmers), then they wouldn't have put any secrets in there. :)

Comment: fyi those are copyrighted images which SE probably doesn't have the rights to use. Obviously there won't be any trouble though.

Comment: Hint: the secret hats are not in that sprite. They have their own images. I didn't look *right* through it, but I think that the troll etc. are just having fun trying to mislead you.

Comment: The beard is not on here.

Comment: Jesus.... i want beard ...how to get this

Comment: Aw man! Hats have gotten better since 2012. Still miss the older ones really!

Answer (score 23):

You can find out how to unlock a particular hat by going to to the [leader board](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com) then hover your mouse over a hat that someone has to see the requirements.

For example, hovering my mouse over the bow tie...

[image: bow tie]

Or you can place the hat name in the URL, http://winterba.sh/epic-punyon-beard and it will show you more details like...

[image: more details]

Comment: Very helpful thx.

Answer (score 18):

Here's the first "secret" hats I got:

[image]

But... I'm not going to tell you how to get them, it will just spoil the fun.

Comment: I want the cupcake!

Comment: [Please tell me the secret behind `The Abby` and `Cake is Not A Lie`](http://i.imgur.com/uPvYi.jpg)

Comment: @hims056 The Abby is something you do a lot, you'll get it very soon...

Comment: @AustinHenley The cake takes a bit of effort, but it's worth it.

Comment: @Yannis Something everyone does a lot or just @hims056?!?

Comment: -1: why do you get secret hats and I don't? ;-)

Comment: @AustinHenley Something I hope everyone does (but not everyone can, there's a rep requirement).

Comment: Ok, if no one says it, im going to explode >_>

Comment: So there is a correct way and an incorrect way... hmmmm..

Comment: @yentup Heh, perhaps there's a secret hat for exploding!

Comment: @AustinHenley Unfortunately, I don't think you can get the cupcake _right_ now, you'll need a bit more rep for it.

Comment: @Yannis That is practically discrimination. Lower rep people need cupcakes too.

Comment: @Yannis: that just means it needs approval by others.

Comment: I saw that bowtie when I looked at the Winter Bash Site, seems to be very common. So an easy to get sectret hat, makes the users want to collect more secret hats, and maybe even leads them to do random crazy stuff :) so yes,I guess it will be a bit of madness. I am actually now trying to get a secret hat, by using all available characters in a comment, up to the last one. I will let you know if it worked and I got the USE ALL CHARACTERS IN A COMMENT hat. Unfortunately it takes a while to type all that, but I am there soon.That would really be a creative secret hat, that maybe nobody discovers!

Comment: hmm, seems not to work, at least not on meta :)

Comment: These comments are getting a little too much. I'm downvoting the answer for promoting needless, unconstructive blabber.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Purge, purge, purge!

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: but isn't "needless, unconstructive blabber" pretty much business as usual for (most of) meta?

Comment: Maybe it just mean to type the alphabet!? aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ and letter 1234567890`,../';][\=-_+ ? or some more  edits?

Comment: I'm surprised no one has found the easter egg on winterba.sh homepage yet. To make it appear, you just h

Comment: @Jin Have to wait a specific, beardy related time? I am looking at it has now, but the eight hour seems so distand. Will the beardy bless come? Maybe it is the Great Pumpkin King, of Peanuts memories? Time will tell.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, [there are secret hats](http://winterba.sh/faq):

[image]

This can also be confirmed by looking at the screenshot in [Hats list in profile should include each hat's name and description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159172/hats-list-in-others-profiles-should-include-each-hats-name). The image is of [Aarthi's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165582/aarthi) hats list, and there are three (Cupcake, Bowtie, Propeller Beanie) which don't appear on the [Winterbash](http://winterba.sh/) main page.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there are, and we're actually keeping a list of them over on Arqade:

- **[What are the Secret Hats for 2012?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/what-are-the-secret-hats-for-2012)**

Answer (score 5):

Another secret hat!

[image] [image]

I will not say which one is this but it is very difficult to earn this hat.

Comment: I hate to spoil the fun, but it comes from getting 15 hats :)

Comment: @NewAlexandria We can see the description everywhere now :)

Comment: Wow these must be cool really! Not sure they work in 2022 though!

Answer (score 4):

You can find out how a certain user acquired a secret hat by visiting their profile and clicking on the hats count.

[image: Hat Stats]

A list of their hats will appear. Hover over a hat to see the action that will obtain this hat.

Comment: But how will you find which user has secret hat?

Comment: @hims056 Look for [people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162704/yannis) boasting about it. Also look at the [leaderboard](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com)

Comment: This is the only serious answer to the question.