# Why are there no tinfoil hats?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2012, fun, hat-request

Ever since the StackOverflow conspiracy was [first discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41288/the-stack-overflow-conspiracy-dont-tell-jeff-im-on-to-him) we know we have been living with all our imaginary Internet dollar points at risk.

The Winter Bash would be the perfect opportunity to put an end to that risk, but it turns out that there is no tinfoil hat that we can obtain to protect ourselves from the evil that spreads forth from Jeff Atchocolate.

Also, even though it is not Friday, it is Summer in the Southern hemisphere.

Comment: How can you be so sure there are no tinfoil hats? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159186/are-there-any-secret-hats

Comment: I am trying to figure how I can be sure. The conspiracy runs deep.

Comment: They exist as a secret hat on area51.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hahah! I am now protected by the power of tinfoil!

[image]

Comment: we made this hat just for you.

Comment: Oh wow, now I got a Bounty Hunter hat.

Answer (score 28):

[Serious Answer]: When we were going to do custom hats for each site, we talked about tinfoil hats for MSO and Skeptics (as a joke!) but then realized: there just wasn't time. We'll consider them for next year, as hopefully we'll have time for per-site hats in the future.

[Unserious Answer]: If we gave you tinfoil hats, it would only confirm your suspicions. And we can't have that, now can we? *Votem et circenses!*

Answer (score 10):

Winter bash with hats, but no tinfoil hats?  No protection?

`<conspiracy theory>`Coincidence?  I THINK NOT!
`</conspiracy theory>`

Comment: It's entirely possible I wrote this answer for the sole purpose of getting a hat

Comment: *pish posh* Everybody knows that copper foil is superior to tinfoil in providing protection from...well, you know.

Answer (score 8):

I'd expect tin foil hats to be most fashionable on https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/