# Hats that are not offered for users

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any secret hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159186/are-there-any-secret-hats)

When I was collecting my hats on Stack Overflow I just came across a [link](http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/sprite-128.png) that shows all the hats for users but some of these hats are not available in the [winterba.sh](http://winterba.sh/). Are they available for other Stack Exchange sites likes security, superuser, etc.?

Comment: These are secret hats

Comment: Lol .. Nicholas Cage :)

Comment: How does that show all of the hats?  [Shogun is missing.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard)

Comment: See [Are there any secret hats?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159186/169404) and [The mysterious Epic Punyon Beard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159782/169404)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of those are secret hats as mentioned in comments. The more active you are, the more chances are that you might get it. And that list doesn't represent all of the hats(For eg:- the [pirate hat](http://winterba.sh/shiver-me-timbers) is not present there).

Most of these hats should be available in other sites as well. Check the [Winter bash leaderboard](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard/superuser.com) to see some of the hats that are uncovered till now.